# Pi approximation with Montecarlo: Why not just evenly distributed points?

Tags: monte-carlo

With the randomised algorithm for Pi approximation (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/estimating-value-pi-using-monte-carlo/ ), I keep wondering why just using points with an even distance should'n work just as fine.

Obviously, with the montecarlo method you get a better approximation the more random points you generate. But isn't an algorithm that just uses the 10000 in a 100x100 square just as good?

Comment: Look up [low-discrepancy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) also known as "quasi-random numbers" (to be contrasted to both *pseudo*-random numbers and true random numbers).

Comment: What do you mean by "using points with an even distance"? And, in your last sentence, just as good _as what_? I'm sorry but I can't tell what you're trying to ask.

Comment: In practice, using points in a regular grid (or other regular pattern) would likely work just as well as using uniformly random points. Neither is particularly efficient (or consistent) compared to analytical methods for calculating digits of pi. A classical physical method of approximating pi is to cut a circle from a square of some even substrate and compare their weights. Depending on the substrate, either random or regular points can be a better simulation of this.

Comment: @DavidRicherby OP means to use points on a fine grid rather than random points.

Comment: I recommend trying your method out, and comparing the running time of both methods and their resulting accuracy. This might answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Let us compare the efficiency of both methods. The first method generates random points on the unit square $[-1,1]^2$, and checks how many of them lie inside the unit circle – the fraction should be $\pi/4$. If we sample $N$ points, our estimate has roughly normal distribution with mean $\pi/4$ and variance $\pi/4(1-\pi/4)/N$, and so we expect an error of order $1/\sqrt{N}$.

The second method generates an $M \times M$ grid inside $[-1,1]^2$ (we can take $M = \sqrt{N}$ for later comparison), and checks how many of the $M^2$ points lie inside the unit circle. If we think of each point as standing in for a grid square, then we can estimate the number of problematic squares (those intersecting the circle) as $\Theta(M)$ out of the $M^2$, leading to an overall error of order $1/M = 1/\sqrt{N}$, just as before.

We can speed up the second method, however: for a given value of $x$, we can use binary search to locate the $y$ coordinates at which the circle crosses the grid. This gives an $O(M\log M)$ algorithm, an almost quadratic speedup over the two algorithms mentioned above. This is very similar to evaluating the integral $2\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx$, implementing the square root using a binary search.